# How is ClojureScript's async library implemented in the browser?

Tags: asynchronous, clojurescript, core.async

I'm trying to wrap my head around the fundamentals of ClojureScript, mainly its async library. I have quite a decent understanding of the JavaScript model with its single threaded event loop, and how it interacts with the ambient browser environment without blocking (Timers, AJAX requests, DOM events etc.).

Considering Clojure/Script has an async library that uses CSPs, I was just wondering how it pulls this off in the single threaded JavaScript environment? My understanding is that you need something analogous to a thread pool for your "green threads" of whatever you call the light weight thread analogues that host the channels.

Under the hood does ClojureScript use webworkers or something like that? 
I'm hesitant to use a tool like this without the faintest idea as to how it's implemented.

Any general answers or links to relevant resources are appreciated.

Comment: Almost certainly not webworkers, the communication overhead is quite high. And I'm pretty sure you could implement CSP using callbacks (although it'd be gnaw-your-arm-off ugly), no threads needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to see the details you can look at the source code:

https://github.com/clojure/core.async/tree/master/src/main/clojure/cljs/core

See also the README under **Documentation** and **Presentations**.

Comment: Or alternatively, a [CSP implementation in JavaScript](https://github.com/ubolonton/js-csp).